# How to select a development team in Xcode 12.3

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I keep getting the following warning in my iOS project:

> Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the [project name] editor.

I've created a "Personal Team" using my iCloud email but I'm not seeing the option to select it in the project editor.

[image: Signing Section]

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add your apple account into Xcode:

1. Go to Xcode preferences -> Accounts
2. Click the plus button at the bottom-left corner.
3. Add your Apple developer account from here.

Now come back to the project editor and you should be able to see your team in the drop-down.

Comment: So I need an Apple developer account in order for a team to show up? I added my iCloud email in Accounts but nothing is showing up.

Comment: yes, you need an Apple developer account or you should be a part of an Apple developer account team.